# StackOverflowError in deeply nested JSON using Jackson only on Dalvik

Tags: android, jackson, retrofit

I'm trying to parse a bunch of JSON which contains a really deeply nested tree of nodes. Here's the POJO:

```
class Node {
    @JsonProperty("children") private List<Node> children;
    @JsonProperty("text") private String text;
}
```

Eventually the tree ends with a Node with an empty list of children. I am using Retrofit to communicate with my server and Jackson to parse the sent JSON.

Parsing a deep tree (say 50 nodes deep) works fine on any Android device using the ART runtime (Android 5.0 and above), however causes a StackOverflowException on any Dalvik device (Android 4.4 and below). You can test this by setting an Android 4.4 device to ART in the developer settings and the JSON is parsed with no problem. [Here's the stack trace I'm getting](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpm5ozraosqez73/stack_trace.txt?dl=0).

Parsing a very short tree (<10 nodes) works on Dalvik.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that ART has a bigger stack size than the Dalvik had. Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html#Stack_Size). Also there is a [Thread constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)  that you can use to specify stack size needed explicitly

Comment: Thanks for the links. You're right that I'm blowing the small amount of stack space on Dalvik. Unfortunately, I don't think I can increase the stack size on Jackson's thread since it's started by Retrofit. Even better would be if I could get Jackson to not use recursion.